# TeXstudio: \ref and \eqref auto-completion

Tags: auto-completion

I've read quite a few questions and answers on this web site but none helps me to resolve my problem. I am using `\ref` and `\eqref` commands most often. After installing and re-installing the latest version of TeXstudio (2.10.0, 5.5.0), in some files the command `\ref` offers a list of available labels, but in some it gives an empty list although the file itself contains plenty of labels.  At the same time, `\eqref` does not work at all. I would be grateful if somebody could help! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't use such editors, but I could imagine that TeXStudio needs an `.aux` file to get the labels from?

Comment: TeXstudio rolled out an update (2.10.2) yesterday, in the changelog it says `- fix detection of \ref commands`

Comment: @Christian -- you are right, TeXstudio does need .aux files.

Comment: @Francis, thanks. Downloaded and tried. \ref or \eqref did not work until TeXstudio completely re-installed. Now \ref works, but \eqref does not.

Comment: @AlexSobolev: I am using TeXstudio 2.10.2 and have no problem with either `\ref` or `\eqref`. Have you tried completely uninstalling TeXstudio and removing all user profile (e.g. in AppData for Windows)?

Comment: @Francis, thanks for the idea. I have tried to uninstall and re-install TeXstudio deleting all files associated. Last time I did this last night, but today I am having the same problem. Our sysadmin told me that this had been reported by a few other users, and it seems to be a genuine bug in the programme.

Comment: @AlexSobolev: Sorry to hear that, hope they will fix this soon

Answer (score 3):

When `\ref` offers the list of labels but `\eqref` does not, add
`\eqref{key}#r` to your `.cwl` file. Then save it, close TeXstudio and again open TeXstudio.

I found it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/64492928/) and it solved the problem for me. Unfortunately, I don't have a link to an explanation of `key` and `#r` or of `.cwl`'s in general.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [known bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1480/) in TeXstudio 2.10.X that is still not fixed in the current release 2.10.8;
but there is a workaround, which worked for me and does not cause problems as far as I can tell:

```
For now, txs generates cwl files for syntax checking.
Please make sure that those files don't contain "\ref#S" or  "\label#S".
Just delete those lines and it should work again.
```

See also [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-the-settings-stored) on where to find the cwl files.

Comment: It works here. That ( http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1480/ ) minimal example with bug works fine here. I'm using TXS 2.10.8

Comment: I guess it depends on which cwl files you activate by default (under setting - completion)

Comment: I had activated a lot of cwl files by default (by checking them in the config dialog), so also the minimal example did not work for me. I did not erase my configuration before updating, which might solve the issue, as well. In case the OP has similar configuration than I have/had, he might profit from the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As of version version 2.10.8 the default cwl files are built in and [cannot by modified directly](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#where-are-cwl-files-stored)

For newer versions TXS searches for cwl files in three different locations:

1. settings directory/completion/user
2. builtin cwls
3. settings directory/completion/autogenerated

you may have a look at the [source code of the buitlin cwls](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/hg/ci/default/tree/completion/). In OSX, create a `custom.cwl` under `/Users/username/.config/texstudio/completion/user/`
with the following:

```
\eqref{label}#r
# \FG{label}#r
```

If like me you have defined custom commands to consistently label figures, tables, sections (e.g. `\newcommand{\FG}[1]{Fig.~\ref{#1}}`), adding them to the custom.cwl makes the completion work for them too.

Last, you need to restart your TexStudio and enabled custom.cwl in the TexStudio settings: Preferences -> Completion